# How to hide the "Edit" button in an asp.net FormView control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview

I would like to hide the "EditButton" located in the ItemTemplate of a FormView control.

Here's is the OnDataBound code of the FormView that I have tried:

```
protected void fvPhaudDets_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name).GetAuthorizationGroups();

        IEnumerable<string> groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.Name);

        string mode = fvPhaudDets.CurrentMode.ToString();
        lblCrntMode.Text = mode;

        if (fvPhaudDets.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
        {
            Button editbtn = fvPhaudDets.FindControl("EditButton") as Button;

            //Determine authorization based on the user's AD security groups
            if (groupNames.Contains("SecGroup1"))
            {
                editbtn.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                editbtn.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the error I get:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Maybe the issue is that the code is being executed prior to the entire FormView being rendered on the page?

How can I modify the code to make sure the "EditButton" in the FormView's ItemTemplate is hidden if the current user is a member of SecGroup1?

**--EDIT--**

This works as expected...

```
if (fvPhaudDets.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.ReadOnly)
    {
        LinkButton editbtn = fvPhaudDets.FindControl("EditButton") as LinkButton;

        if (editbtn != null && groupNames.Contains("SecGroup1"))
        {
            editbtn.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws your error?

Comment: It happens on "editbtn.visible = false;" in the if statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thanks for the link @dee-dee.  I understand now that the evaluation starts before the FormView is completely loaded, but doesn't complete until it is.  So, a simple modification to evaluate whether or not the button was null is all it took.  I'll post the change for others who may find this.

Comment: can you post the formview asp.net UI code also?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void fvPhaudDets_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          ((LinkButton) ((FormView)sender).FindControl("EditButton")).Visible = false;// Hides Edit button
          ((LinkButton) ((FormView)sender).FindControl("NewButton")).Visible = false;// Hides New button
          ((LinkButton) ((FormView)sender).FindControl("DeleteButton")).Visible = false;// Hides Delete button
        }
```

Another solution: edit the template then either change the property of the link button to `Visible= false` or delete the button itself from the template.